# Flutter: onSaved method of TextFormField not storing values to variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form which prompts the user to enter the address. The form is broken down into multiple TextFormField widgets which is defined in a file called `address_widget.dart`. These widgets are called from the file: `AddressPage.dart`. The form loads and gets validated properly but the values saved by the onSaved methods in `address_widget.dart` is not getting stored in the variables `city` and `address` in `AddressPage.dart`. When printing the variables `city` and `address`, null is printed. Is this the correct way to do it or am I missing something?

***address_widget.dart***

```
Widget buildCity(city) {
    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        fontSize: 2 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'City',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'This field is Required';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        city = value;
      },
    );
}

Widget buildAddress(address) {
    return TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        fontSize: 2 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Address',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'This field is Required';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        address = value;
      },
    );
}
```

***AddressPage.dart***

```
import 'package:userproject/widgets/address_widget.dart';

class AddressPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddressPageState createState() => _AddressPageState();
}

class _AddressPageState extends State<AddressPage> {
  
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String city;
  String address;  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Form(
               key: _formKey,
               child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Enter your Address',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        buildCity(city),
                        buildAddress(address),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                       return;
                                 }
                                 _formKey.currentState.save(); 

                                print("city - $city"); // prints null
                                print("address- $address"); // prints null
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    }
}
```

The code has been simplified for easy reference.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a `TextEditingController` to get the data from the text field.

```
class _AddressWidgetState extends State<AddressWidgetScreen> {
  
  final myController = TextEditingController();
//a string to store the input from the text field
  String city = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
//in your case TextFormField
        TextField(
  controller: myController,
),
 RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //store the data from textfield to our new string
              city = myController.text.toString();
      //therest of your logic
            },
   
            textColor: Colors.white,),
```

**BONUS TIP**

Also, as good practice you should look to validate forms in a different class on runtime, using [ValueObjects](https://resocoder.com/2020/03/13/flutter-firebase-ddd-course-2-authentication-value-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onSaved you could try using the onChange callBack method it get assigned when ever the value gets changed.
In order to use the on SavedMethod the a separate formKey must be added to the form section and then we should call the onSaved using the context of the key which we have assigned.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered Hot Restart?
some code changes are not implemented until you do a 'Hot Restart'